# jqgrid freeze columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid and I had to freeze couple of columns in the grid. I see that there is no way to do this using current version of jggrid. Is it possible to use other jquery plugins with jqgrid to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/new-freeze-column-plugin/

I have tried, but it isn't prefect !, hope Trirand supports it soon.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried that already but it kind of messed the look of the table. I tried another workaround for internet explorer, using css classes

Answer (score 2):

There is official Frozen columns in jqgrid now:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns