# How to show and implement column freeze in jqgrid in user interface

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jqgrid, freeze

[Freezing Columns in JQGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481996/freezing-columns-in-jqgrid)

describes how to use jqGrid 4.3 frooze column feature in code.

Frozen column border is not visible and there is no users interface to frooze/unfrooze columns.

How to allow end users to use this feature for selection any number of columns, for example:

1. Double click in column border in header froses left columns
2. Frozed columns border line becomes bold, wider and changes color a little

How to implement this or any other way to froze/unfroze and show frozen columns?

This is posted also in

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/provide-user-interface-for-column-freeze-and-show-frozen-column-border-graphically/

Comment: +1 I think the question is interesting. I wrote my opinion about the suggestion in the [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/provide-user-interface-for-column-freeze-and-show-frozen-column-border-graphically/#p25428).

Comment: Thank you very much. From Tony answer it looks like this enhancement request is not accepted.

Comment: Yes, I read the answer. In one point I can agree with Tony: one can create interface which you asked independent from the main code of jqGrid. I think the easiest way would be to create context menu in the column header with items like "freeze/unfreeze", "hide", "column chooser" or some other.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possbile to add those commands to the context menu you created ? jqGrid freeze API requires column number. How to find it in your contextmenu creator? however the visual appertance issue exists. how to show in jqgrid visually that columns are froozen. I ask this from Tony, he does not respond for this part of feature request

Comment: @Oleg: Tony provides instructions in reply: You can style this using the folowing classe: "frozen-div" is the class for the frozen header
"frozen-bdiv" is the class for the frozen data